# how to apply if condition based on date format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

in a folder I have multiple csv files. Few files have date format in 2022-01-01 format and few in 01/01/2022. I have set date as index in all files. Now I need to parse the dates. I am using below method:

```
if df.index.format() == "%Y-%m-%d":
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.index), format="%Y-%m-%d")
else:
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.index), format="%D/%m/%Y")
```

However its not working. Can you please correct me.

Comment: Are the date formats consistent in each file or can one file contain multiple date formats?

Comment: each file has consistent date format. One file doesn't have diff formats.

Comment: Then you should just be able to use the param `infer_datetime_format=True` and skip the condition. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, infer_datetime_format=True))`

Comment: it is giving me an error- _UserWarning: Parsing '13/10/2016' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.
  data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, infer_datetime_format=True)_

Comment: That is a warning not an error letting you know how it is parsing the dates. If it is the correct format (DD/MM/YYYY) then everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you using **convtools** library as a helper here ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) | [Table docs](https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html)).

The code below assumes there's a file named `input.csv`, it has header and the date column, you are talking about, is named `dt`. Comment below if the assumptions are not correct, I would adjust the answer to better fit your data.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table


def parse_date(dt_str, __strptime=datetime.strptime):
    try:
        return __strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return __strptime(dt_str, "%d/%m/%Y")


pd.DataFrame(
    Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=True)
    .update(
        Date=c.col("Date").pipe(parse_date),
        # e.g. we need to explicitly transform some columns
        **{
            column_name: c.col(column_name).as_type(int)
            for column_name in ("Number", "Value")
        },
    )
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c

def parse_date(dt_str, __strptime=datetime.strptime):
    try:
        return __strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return __strptime(dt_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
with c.OptionsCtx() as options:
    data = pd.DataFrame(Table.from_csv("myFile.csv", header=True)\
    .update(c=c.col("Date").pipe(parse_date)).into_iter_rows(dict))
```

Comment: @westandskif above code converted my whole dataframe numbers into string. Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a better example, which includes type casting. The table helper uses simple csv.reader under the hood, which doesn't cast anything to numbers automatically. Tools like pandas implicitly tries to cast everything, what leads to file mutations after read/write cycle.